# Sans serif fonts in block headers while using another package

Tags: fonts, fontspec, beamerposter

I'm brand new to TeX and am making my first `beamerposter`.  I'm using XeLaTeX and I like the package `pxfonts` for the math and the body text.  However, I'd like to have sans serif text in the block headers, and I don't like the default sans serif font that results from the `pxfonts` package.  Can someone explain to me, in simple terms, why I cannot use the package `fontspec` to modify the sans serif font after I have loaded `pxfonts`?  And what should I use instead?

Consider the code below.  How can I change the font of the sans-serif part while keeping the first paragraph and the equation as they currently appear?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pxfonts}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\[
\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = 1/3
\]

\sffamily \blindtext %This is the text whose font I wish to change to something already loaded on my computer.
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Comment: Can you add an example of code?

Comment: @egreg Actually the whole beamerposter context is unimportant.  Really I just want to know how to switch between the serif and sans-serif font...without having to use the default sans-serif font provided by `pxfonts`.

Comment: The content is unimportant, but it's easier for us to have some code to play with, rather than starting from scratch.

Comment: @egreg Alright, does this edit help?

Comment: @ChrisS My issue is different because I want to use `fontspec` only for certain contexts, and the package `pxfonts` for others.  The question you've cited merely shows how to switch between various fonts using `fontspec`.

Comment: You can't use `fontspec` for part and `pxfonts` for part as I understand it. You can certainly use `pxfonts` and change the sans-serif afterwards. But if you insist on doing so with `fontspec` you are out of luck. Why not simply use `fontspec`? What does `pxfonts` do which `fontspec` cannot?

Comment: @cfr I want Palatino font for my math equations, but math-supported Palatino is not stored on my computer.

Comment: @cfr I'm ok with not using `fontspec` if you have some alternative method to achieve my desired result...

Comment: @cfr Actually you mentioned that "You can certainly use pxfonts and change the sans-serif afterwards."  Where would this be done?

Comment: What do you want to change it to? You could use `mathpazo` before `fontspec`, by the way.

Comment: @cfr Optima.  (I get the error that 'uop' is not found when I do it the obvious way...)

Comment: You'd have to use something which you have installed for TeX i.e. not a system font but one from your TeX installation.

Comment: @cfr I tried using `mathpazo` before `fontspec` and everything was changed to cmr!!

Comment: @ cfr This website: http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/optima/ says that I should have it...

Comment: That site is mistaken if you have TeX Live. I don't know about MiKTeX. If you have TeX Live, you can install it by running `getnonfreefonts-sys` and selecting the appropriate package. The script will handle the installation etc. Optima cannot be distributed as part of TeX Live.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Optima by running `getnonfreefonts-sys` and selecting the appropriate package if you have TeX Live. Once the font is installed you can use this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uop}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\[
\int_0^1 x^2 \, dx = 1/3
\]

\sffamily \blindtext %This is the text whose font I wish to change to something already loaded on my computer.
\end{document}
```

[image: Palatino with Optima]